# Blacklist the [engine] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request, tag-block-request

[image: bat signal]

The tag [engine](/questions/tagged/engine) is not meaningful enough to keep around; it doesn't even have a tag wiki (what would that even contain?). Can we disallow it?

Comment: There are a bunch of specialized `[-engine]` tags that some of these should be retagged to, e.g. `[search] + [engine] -> [search-engine]` etc.

Comment: Oh and there's also the plural version `[engines]` which should be eliminated as well.

Comment: [tag:engines] now has 0 posts